# Supress show download dialog box in webbrowser

Tags: c#, dialog, webbrowser-control

I use webbrowser to show web page. I have link which I must click to show other control. But problem is that this click execute download dialog box which I don't need.

It is way to block showing dialog only for moment?

Comment: can you add url of target for test?add code

Comment: What's the type of file your link is pointing to?

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid it you need to turn off the auto download box on internet explorer--Security  settings.

[image]

Comment: Now it show a pop up telling due security reasons the download can't be done.